# How to get all d3.js charts on one page

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have piechart.html and a barchart.html and I've included them in another html.Both charts are getting overlapped with each other.I have used svg in both pie and bar.I think this is the issue .How can I solve this problem

```
My pie code:
===========
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

My Bar code:
==========
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rename the variables for each chart:

```
var svgPie = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("class","pie-chart")
```

and

```
var svgBar = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("class","bar-chart")
```

Then apply the logic on each chart individually.

Comment: Well, you wrote the code, you should know. All methods for the pie chart should be on the `svgPie` variable, and the ones for the bar chart, on the `svgBar` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use bootstrap to segregate the page into sections and call the chart rendering function(depends on the kind of library you have created using d3) with the ids of the div.

var renderContainer=d3.select('#'+renderContainerId);

function render(renderContainer){

renderContainer.append('svg')

more code goes here to appends rectangles, pies, etc... to the svg

}